# For Standard Mode, is conditional CSS necessary for IE?

Tags: css, doctype, quirks-mode

If the HTML page has a proper doctype, is conditional CSS still necessary for IE?

Today I heard that, if the doctype has been added and the page is rendered in Standard mode, a lot of IE specific fixes, which were for the pages in Quirks mode, would be no longer unnecessary. Is it true?

Comment: There are still plenty of IE only bugs in standards mode.

Comment: The question is overly broad and based on undisclosed assumptions (like assuming need for “conditional CSS” for unspecified reasons, and false assumption about “the doctype” causing Quirks Mode). It cannot be answered constructively.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Quirks mode and its association with the document type (and more recently, `meta http-equiv`) is well-documented for Internet Exploder from versions 4 to 10 inclusive, both on MSDN and in the web Q&A. What makes you say that the OP's question is based on false assumptions?

Comment: @Damon, there is no such documentation (you cannot name one), and it is surely a false premise that a “proper doctype” triggers Quirks Mode (rather the exact opposite). It is also a false premise that “conditional CSS” was ever necessary as a general assumption.

Comment: [One of about 50 pages on Microsoft's site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/14/interoperable-html5-quirks-mode-in-ie10.aspx) that states no more and no less than that the current version of IE runs in quirks mode when any DOCTYPE other than the empty HTML5 one is used. That means _every valid webpage_ in the world which uses the currently valid, finalized and approved standard. Feel free to search yourself for the respective docs relating to prior versions, I'm too tired to prove you wrong and argue about nothing. :-)

Comment: @Damon - The page you link to doesn't say what you think it says. What it says, is that in addition to their being no DOCTYPE. a **specific set** of doctypes as defined in the HTML5 spec will invoke a quirks mode that is consistent with the quirks mode behaviour provided in Firefox, Chrome etc for that same specific set of doctypes. That's a good thing, no?

Comment: HTML5 specifies **any** DOCTYPE as legacy, except one that's just "html", which includes every presently valid document. HTML5 is not a valid standard. We can talk about HTML5 in 2014, but for the time being, it's a candidate recommendation with partial support in some browsers, which means just about nothing. No doctype and a doctype without version is simply not allowable in the currently valid standard. But that's besides the point. What I'm opposing to is pointing at the OP and yelling out "false assumptions" for asking an entirely legitimate thing based on _well documented_ behaviour.

Comment: @Damon, I understand your point now. Let me put this question in this way. If the page has the proper HTML5 doctype, would it possible that browsers render differently?

Comment: @GraceShao: If every browser was perfect, no. As it is, browsers are written by humans, and do behave differently even when they shouldn't. Assuming the user has a reasonably new browser version (which you don't know!) the differences will be very small. Microsoft has been weird with their browsers, for example IE9 does not run on Windows XP and IE10 does not currently run on anything older than Windows 8. There are no technical reasons for that, it's just politics. Now, with a current market share of ~1.2% for Windows 8, general IE10 availability to date is not that great.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a special style sheet for IE. There are some bugs and differences in some browsers, but it's usually better to just circumvent them rather than writing browser specific styles.

Using more robust solutions that works the same in all browsers makes it more likely that the code will continue to work with future browsers also.

Even when you need to add fixes specifically for IE, some can be done without causing problems for other browsers. For example adding `display:inline` on floating elements, or setting a specific size on an element.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes it would cause us to work backwards - to get designers' agreements to do some changes. For this question, I want to know, are the conditional CSS and doctype related?

Comment: @GraceShao: I wonder what's in a design that would require conditional CSS, I can't really think of anything... If you don't have a doctype then browsers act up in many different ways, so then conditional CSS might be helpful, but using a doctype and using conditional CSS is not directly related.

Comment: Our pages are not having doctype right now, which was a big mistake (long story). I was wondering having doctype would fix a lot things without having conditional CSS for IE.

Comment: @GraceShao: Yes, having a doctype will definitely fix a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

While including the doctype declaration certainly helps, Internet Explorer, prior to version 9 and in a gradually increasing fashion going back through the versions, behaves differently enough to standards compliant browsers that you will struggle to get away without Internet Explorer specific fixes except in the most basic of cases.

The key thing is that the doctype declaration goes a long way to getting IE there, but not all of the way and you will need to make tradeoffs. I'm not sure exactly which problems the doctype fixes, I believe it is a number of issues. Personally I include a valid doctype regardless.